# ProgressBar doesn't rotating in universal image loader

Tags: android, progress-bar, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal Image Loader to load pictures for custom info window in google maps. I want to add progress bar, while images are loading.

I've tried, but it doesn't rotating :(

Here piece of code for loading images:

```
final ImageView image = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge));            
final ProgressBar spinner = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);

imageLoader.displayImage(url, image, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {                                            
     @Override
     public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
          spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          image.setVisibility(View.GONE);
     }              

     @Override
     public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri,View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
          super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
          image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
          getInfoContents(marker);
     }                                      
});
```

ImageView and ProgressBar in custom_info_window.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/badge"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="270dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    style="@style/ProgressTheme"
    android:max="100" />
```

green_progress.xml:

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toDegrees="720"
android:repeatCount="infinite">

<shape
    android:innerRadiusRatio="5"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="15"
    android:useLevel="false" >
    <size
        android:height="48dip"
        android:width="48dip" />

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:centerY="0.50"            
        android:endColor="#c1d82f"
        android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:type="sweep"
        android:useLevel="false" />
</shape>
```

And styles:

```
<style
    name="ProgressTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Large" >

    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/green_progress</item>        
</style>
```